# How to read a datafile from another folder without giving full path in python?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

In my google drive I have a folder called `Colab Notebooks/data/`, How can I append this path to system, so that I dont have to give the full name of data file ?

My attempt:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
dat_dir = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/data/' 

# read data
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv(dat_dir + 'titanic_kaggle_train.csv') # this works
```

## I want this

```py
pd.read_csv('titanic_kaggle_train.csv') # Here, I dont have full path
```

## I tried

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(dat_dir) # did not work

# another attempt (did not work)
!export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/data/:$PYTHONPATH
```

## Question

How can this command work?

```py
pd.read_csv('titanic_kaggle_train.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this, what you are searching (change the working directory using `os.chdir`:

```
import os
os.chdir(dat_dir)
pd.read_csv('titanic_kaggle_train.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a one-line magic.

```
%cd drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/data/
```